# Watson Conversations bug? Triggering "Not found" logic even though the slot's entity is found

Tags: watson-conversation

I'm having a problem: One of my slots is supposed to gather a user's location (one of several known possibilities), and even though the entity is recognized in the user's answer, the slot's "Not found:" logic is triggering.

Worth noting: the variable gets assigned correctly, and it does move on to the next slot instead of retrying.

[image: Slot config]

[image: Successfully recognizes entity AND moves on to the next slot]

[image: Debug log]

Comment: First thing that comes into my mind is if the JSON frame specification is correct. Sometimes it might happen that UI and JSON gets desynchronized which can then lead to some non-standard specification in the JSON of the chatbot that could potentially lead to these kind of weird issues. Would it be possible for you to provide also the JSON of the chatbot with this issue (e.g. you could send it to my email michal.bida [at] cz.ibm.com ). A minimal sub-set of chatbot triggering this issue is fine (in this example probably, only the frame + entities).